# How to create a new dataframe with only the first day of every quarter or month or week from a daily timeseries data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have the following dataframe from 2008 to 2021.
how do I pick only the first day of every quarter. i.e. first day of Jan, April, July, Oct.
Or how do I pick the first day of every month or week for that matter from a daily time.

```
             IJR_Close  BND_Close
Date                             
2008-01-02   32.195000  77.360001
2008-01-03   31.785000  77.459999
2008-01-04   30.815001  77.550003
2008-01-07   30.975000  77.570000
2008-01-08   30.120001  77.650002
```

The resulting dataframe should be

```
             IJR_Close  BND_Close
Date                             
2008-01-02   32.195000  77.360001
2008-04-01   34.785000  79.859999
2008-07-01   36.815001  80.350003
2008-10-02   33.975000  80.470000
2009-01-01   31.120001  80.450002
```

Please help !

Comment: Well if you use `dt.is_quarter_start` you'll drop off stuff like `YYYY-01-02`. I would offset them to quarter start, then pick first.

Comment: If you want the first day of every month or week, resample to that level.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `groupby` with `head`

```
df.groupby(df.index.isocalendar().week).head(1)
Out[48]: 
            IJR_Close  BND_Close
Date                            
2008-01-02     32.195  77.360001
2008-01-07     30.975  77.570000
```

Comment: I decided to resample my data by monthly instead of having a large data frame and then cutting it down.